# Django view to be created with the previous request containing select tag

Tags: python, django-views, form-submit

I am developing a webapp in Django+Python.

I have three **radio** button inputs, which are having the job of showing and hiding the required **select** tag's ( done in Jquery ). i.e. With the check of one of the radio option its respective select element is visible and the rest is hidden.

Now, with the select element having its purpose for selecting a price range

```
<select name="price1" id="selPriceRange1" style="display:none" disabled > 
    <option value="1" >Below 400</option> 
    <option value="2" >400 to 600</option> 
    <option value="3" >600 to 1000</option> 
    <option value="4" >1000 to 1500</option> 
    <option value="5" >1500 to 2000</option> 
    <option value="6" >2000 to 2500</option> 
    <option value="7" >2500 to 4000</option> 
    <option value="8" >4000 to 7000</option> 
    <option value="9" >7000 to 15000</option> 
</select>
```

I have three similar select ranges for three radio buttons. If you can observe, the value i have given to them is '1','2',... Now the problem i am facing is to create view when i submit the data.

Here is my view function:

```
def search(request):
    if 'txtSearch' in request.GET and request.GET['txtSearch']:
        place = request.GET['txtSearch']
        typeOfPro = request.GET['property']
        typeOfPlace = request.GET['selToplace']

        if 'price1' in request.GET:
              price = request.GET['price1']
        elif 'price2' in request.GET:
          price = request.GET['price2']
        else:
          price = request.GET['price3']

        ghar = GharData.objects.filter(place__icontains=place, typeOfProperty__icontains=typeOfPro, typeOfPlace__icontains=typeOfPlace)
        return render_to_response('gharnivas/searchresult.html',{'ghar': ghar },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('gharnivas/ghar.html', {'error': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here `txtSearch`,`property` are also my form data that is submitted.

The problem I face is how will i check the value of the data from `select` tag? I mean since i thought of keeping the value '1','2',... And if the database had the actual value as $12000 as the value. Then how can i achieve this:

```
ghar = GharData.objects.filter(place__icontains=place, typeOfProperty__icontains=typeOfPro, typeOfPlace__icontains=typeOfPlace)
```

Can some thing be used as a comparison and should i do it or

> how do I compare the stored data with
>   the data present in database?

Please if someone can provide a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your numbers don't correspond in any mathematical way to the actual values, you'll need to simply map them via a dict. Then you can pass the result of that map to a `__range` query:

```
VALUE_MAP = {
    "1", (0, 399),
    "2", (400, 599),
    "3", (600, 1000),
    ...
}
value_range = VALUE_MAP[price]

GharData.objects.filter(...other criteria..., value__range=value_range)
```

Comment: Small confusion, after "1" it should be a colon(:) right? I mean the dictionary is what you are suggesting me? And Since I have three such `Select` elements with different range(for ex: in one select I have `value="1" for 4000 to 6000` and in another `value="1" for 200000 to 500000`). You think I should use different dictionaries for different `select` elements ?